# Representing a vector in rotated frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, rotation

If $R \in SO(3) $ is a rotation matrix defined from body fixed frame to the inertial frame such that $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are the basis of inertial frame and $b_1, b_2, b_3$ are the basis of body frame, then what would be the relation between $b_i$ and $e_i$.

According to me, it should be:- $$e_i = Rb_i$$ 
But consistently across several papers I have come across the relation:-  $$b_i = Re_i$$ while describing the quad-rotor dynamics as:- $$ m\dot{v} = mge_3 - fRe_3$$ where $f$ is the magnitude of force by propellers (whose direction is $-b_3$).

One such paper being - [Geometric Tracking Control of a Quadrotor UAV on SE(3) for Extreme Maneuverability](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~mleok/pdf/LeLeMc2010_extreme.pdf) (Equation - 3).

What is it that I am interpreting wrong? Shouldn't $R$ take a vector from body frame, $i.e. b_3$ to inertial frame $i.e. e_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotations have an ambiguity, and that is whether they are alias or alibi (also called passive or active). The latter rotates a vector to a new position while the former expresses the same vector in different coordinate system. Check to see which you are using, and which the papers are using.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that. I will check.